# ng-map is not compiling in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-google-maps

I included directives such as ngMap,nvd3 in my ang

```html
var app = angular.module('myApp', [ 'nvd3','ngMap']);

angular.module('myApp').
controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter', '$compile',  '$http', '$q', '$log', function($scope,  $compile, $timeout, $http) {

var template = '<div class= "chartsDiv">'
       + ' <div class="col"> <p class="graphtitle"> NetSpend Over Time </p> <nvd3 id = "chart3" options="netspendovertime_options" data="netspendovertime_data"></nvd3> </div>'
       + ' <div class="col"> <p class="graphtitle"> Google Map </p>   <map center="43.07493,-89.381388" zoom="8"> </map> </div>'
       + ' </div>';

});
```

ularJs application.

In the controller prepared two dashboards one is related to nvd3 and another one is related to ngMap. while rendering into browser nvd3 related  dashboard is displaying.ngmap releated dashboard is not displaying.

sample code for creating template is:

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the reference on your header before angular.js ?

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=weather,visualization,panoramio"></script>
```